# Where can one find the full decisional text of R v Hale (1979) 68 Cr App R 415, [1979] Crim. L.R. 596?

Tags: england-and-wales, legal-research, case-law, legal-citation

Can’t seem to find anything other than bare summaries. Can anyone find it anywhere online?

https://lawprof.co/criminal-law/property-offences-cases/r-v-hale-1979-68-cr-app-r-415-1979-crim-l-r-596/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about the law - SE isn't a search engine.

Comment: It’sa question about legal research methods in the face of failure with search engines.

Comment: Erm.. no, this isn't asking people about research methods, you're literally asking people to find a specific text for you.

Comment: @motosubatsu, I would firmly beg to differ: a very valid answer which was of precisely the character of what I was seeking, was “maybe go to a law library”. Not to mention the further explanatory insights that were given by Scott. Pedantic semantics aside, this really is asking about research methods (or specifically sources)

Comment: If what the question is "really asking" is something different than what is actually written in the question then it should be edited.

Comment: Sorry mate this is to my mind a matter of applying basic common sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Criminal Appeal Reports](https://legal.thomsonreuters.com.au/criminal-appeal-reports-parts-bound-volumes-service/productdetail/29276) and [Criminal Law Review](https://www.sweetandmaxwell.co.uk/Product/Criminal-Law/Criminal-Law-Review/Journal/30791441) are commercially published, by Thomson Reuters and Sweet & Maxwell respectively. They are not freely available on the internet; paid access to [Westlaw UK](https://legalsolutions.thomsonreuters.co.uk/en/products-services/westlaw-uk.html) is required. But your nearest law library might have print copies, or a Westlaw terminal, which you can use for free.